# Using OR in Python for a yes/no?

Tags: python

I'm wanting to have a "y/n" in Python, which i've successfully done, but I want the user to be able to input a "y" or a "Y" and it accepts both.

Here's a short if statement

```
if yn == "y":
    break
```

I'm wanting to make it be something like this

```
if yn == "y" || "Y":
    break
```

But "||" is the OR operator in Java. I don't know what the OR operator is in Python or if I could even use it for something like this. Any help?

Comment: Note that the equivalent of `if yn == "y" || "Y"` does not work in practially any programming language. It's either a type error or gives nonsensical results (always true), because it means `if (yn equals "y") or ("Y" is true)`. It does **not** mean `if yn equals either "y" or "Y"`.

Comment: @delnan I know, but for simplicities sake I just used that example.

Comment: @Xiam: How does an example that doesn't make any sense in Java, so we have to guess what you might want it to mean, make things simpler? (It's meaningless in Java for the exact same reason the equivalent code is meaningless in Python.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for

```
if yn in ("y", "Y"):
```

Or better:

```
if yn.lower() == 'y':
```

Answer (score 7):

choose:

```
if yn in ["y","Y"]:
    break

if yn.lower() == "y":
    break
```

Answer (score 5):

It is `or` as in

`if yn == 'y' or yn == 'Y':`.

Although a better method would be

`if yn in ['y', 'Y']:`

or

`if yn.lower() == 'y':`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if yn in "yY":
```

is more succinct than

```
if yn in ['y', 'Y']:
```

or similar statements.  It works because a string is a sequence in Python, just like a list or tuple.

It would evaluate to True if the user enters literally "yY", though.